# Git shows all files as modified after changing file permission

Tags: git

I changed the file permission to 777 of a non-bare git repository on Ubuntu OS. After that all files in the repository is showing as modified. I don't want to add all files again and commit. I want to commit the files that I have edited. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`git config core.fileMode false`

This tells git to ignore exec-bit changes.

Comment: Is there a way to do this globally? Flag `--global` doesn't do anything. I tried `git config --global core.fileMode false` but no cigar.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ignore file permissions changes you can add:

```
git config core.fileMode false
```

to your ~/.gitconfig. See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

```
core.fileMode

If false, the executable bit differences between the index and the working tree are ignored; useful on broken filesystems like FAT. See git-update-index[1].

The default is true, except git-clone[1] or git-init[1] will probe and set core.fileMode false if appropriate when the repository is created.
```