# After deploying GitHub repository into Ubuntu server, all files are viewed as modified

Tags: linux, git, github

I've created an Ubuntu server deployed the GitHub repository there and added permission. After that, all my files show as modified when I run `git status`.

I have tried with `git config core.fileMode false`, `git stash`, and `git reset`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that's the default behavior of git. Did you pull the git repository from GitHub to your server using SSH? Or have you uploaded the files using a tool like FileZilla and then add the remote repository using `git remote add origin` ?

Comment: This solution works for me [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056788/git-shows-all-files-as-modified-after-changing-file-permission) git config core.fileMode false

Comment: @ Eyad Bereh
i just git clone into server

Comment: Which permissions did you change, and what exactly changed?

Comment: @JimRedmond i just run this 
git config core.fileMode false